# In comics, has S.H.I.E.L.D. ever been in this state? (Spoilers for Captain America 2 and Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.)

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, agents-of-shield, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

In Marvel's Cinematic Universe, it has been shown that

> Hydra followers have secretly infiltrated the S.H.I.E.L.D. over several decades.
>
>  Council members of S.H.I.E.L.D. are dead.
>
>  Nick Fury is officially dead and he is living into exile.

*Captain America: The Winter Soldier* and the last episode (S01E17) of *Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* have actively shown this.

Marvel once said in *Marvel Studios: Assembling a Universe* that they have a lot of stuff from comics, that they can bring to Marvel's Cinematic Universe. So, I was wondering if current situation of S.H.I.E.L.D. ever been encountered in comics.

Has S.H.I.E.L.D. ever been doomed in comics? What happened after that?

Comment: Sorry for the spoilers. I have problems hiding bulleted items. Please, hide it.

Comment: If you had problems with the spoiler markup, you should have asked on Meta about spoiler markup with bullets, or put it in spoiler tags without bullets. This is the second time, very recently, where you’ve poster spoilers in the question title. Please be more considerate of other users. (And yes, you got another downvote from me for this.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually yes.  SHIELD was infiltrated by Hydra in the comics.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HYDRA

> After the events of Secret Invasion, Nick Fury discovers that
>   S.H.I.E.L.D. was under the control of HYDRA, and apparently had been
>   from the beginning. He also discovers a number of organizations under
>   HYDRA's alleged control including the United States' FBI Science and
>   Technology Branch, NSA and US Department of Treasury, as well as the
>   Russian Main Intelligence Directorate and Foreign Intelligence Service
>   and the Canadian Security Intelligence Service.
>
> -Secret Warriors #1

Comment: Why did you delete old answer. You could have edited that.

Comment: And, there's no need to hide anything. That comics isn't new.

Comment: Yeah I was at work my computer messed up lol.... Figured if I answered it plain out it would reveal what you were asking originally.

Comment: There’s very little that hasn’t happened in already comics. For example, the *Simpsons Movie* writers might have felt really original coming up with [spider-pig](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=714-Ioa4XQw), despite the fact that [Peter Porker, a.k.a. Spider-Ham](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Ham), was already 24 years old.

Comment: Secret Warriors is actually an excellent series and check it, it's cheap [Nick Fury's Secret Warriors](http://www.ebay.com/itm/S-H-I-E-L-D-Agents-SALE-Nick-Fury-s-Secret-Warriors-COMPLETE-Hickman-/281303790175?pt=US_Comic_Books&hash=item417f03325f)

Comment: For the record, the Ultimate version of SHIELD was also infiltrated at the highest levels by the Chitauri, which is what the MCU version of Hydra is heavily based on (WWII/Nazi origins, advanced technology, etc.)